# Dates in SendLog / VAWP / E-Mail

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

- FirstQuestion: My SendLog dataextension has a field called senddate
  which is automaticly filled by "CurrentDate". Since it is quite
  tricky to change the time i am using a salesforce function called
  `SystemDatetoLocalDate()`. It says this function uses the salesforce user
  setting (on profile center?). Is this the user setting of a
  salesforce marketing cloud user or a setting from a contact in
  profile center. If the second is true, how can i see these values and
  how can i force them into a value i define.
- Second Question: Is it the right way to use functions like `Now()` in
  E-Mail Context and retrieve the SystemDatetoLocalDate from the
  dataextension in VAWP context to be consistent or do i have to implement a different
  logic to have consistent values? Or do i have to use something like `%%[ SET @timeOfSend = Now(true) ]%%`?

Is there anything else you can recommend in this manner? Feel free to share ;)

Comment: Hi Johannes. Are you saying that the senddate is not correct? Is it because of the timezone of your account? Can you explain what was wrong with the default date stamp?

Comment: The CurrentDate which is used inside marketing cloud is based on the timezone of the marketing cloud server. This timezone is CST / CDT? Our company is running in Germany so GMT+1 (UTC+1 or UTC+2)

Answer (score 0):

So as the senddate is not in the right time zone and you want a specific time zone, start by creating a new column of type date.

In your email create a variable and add it the right date/time using one of these function:

- Local Date to System Date
- Now
- System Date to Local Date

Info [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/SystemDateToLocalDate.htm)

If you have the column created and the value assign in your email it should be added to the sendlog DE.

Comment: But which timezone does System Date to Locale Date take? A subscribers timezone? A Marketing Cloud User timezone? CurrentDate in SendLog makes sure the timing of the send is being populated there, is the same true if you assign a variable inside the email and write it into the sendlog?

Comment: You will want to use "SystemDateToLocalDate" and it is based on the Marketing Cloud user's local time, not the SFMC account time zone.